# ошибка при попытке обновить БД (mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, база-данных

Есть две функции - создать заказ, и отредактировать заказ. Первая отрабатывает как надо, но вторая выдает ошибку Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake (mysql). Обьясните, пожалуйста, где я допускаю ошибку.

```js
import mysql from 'mysql';

class db_connect {
constructor(userChatId) {
    this.userChatId = userChatId;
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '<host>',
        user     : '<user>',
        password : '<password>',
        database : 'database'
    });
    this.connectDb();
}

connectDb = () => {
    this.connection.connect()
}
addNewOrder = async () => {
    let data = {userId: this.userChatId};
    console.log(data)
    await this.connection.query('INSERT INTO orders SET ?',data , function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(results)
    });
    this.connection.end();
}

updateOrder = async (data) => {
    this.connectDb();
    await this.connection.query(`UPDATE orders SET ${data.key}=? WHERE userId=${this.userChatId}`, data.value, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(results)
    });
    this.connection.end();
}
}

let x = new db_connect(33333);

x.addNewOrder().then(r=>console.log(r))
x.updateOrder({firstName:"Вася"}).then(r=>console.log(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Поискал получше и нашел топик, где сказано, при использовании node.js убрать connect() и end(). все заработало.